# How to get data from PowerBI link using python?

Tags: python, web-scraping, powerbi

I need to extract the table from the production table: https://app.powerbi.com/view?r=eyJrIjoiNzVmNzI1MzQtNTY1NC00ZGVhLTk5N2ItNzBkMDNhY2IxZTIxIiwidCI6IjQ0OTlmNGZmLTI0YTYtNGI0Mi1iN2VmLTEyNGFmY2FkYzkxMyJ9

But since it is a PowerBI and it doesn't have an export to CSV option, I'm not being able to do so...

Is it possible to do it through XHR?

Any help is very much appreciated!

I tried getting access, but ANP didn't give me. I called them, but they couldn't help me...